How to convert from AutomationElement of uiautomation library to AutomationElement of flaui library?
How to convert an object ele of type **AutomationElement **defined by Microsoft's uiautomationg library（uiautomation） to a flauiEle object of type **AutomationElement **defined by the **flaui **library?
Both uiautomation library and flaui library are for automating the processing of windows desktop windows and their child controls. flaui is a wrapper and optimisation of uiautomation, so then both libraries define the AutomationElement class, just with the same class name. So how do they convert to each other?
Here's my c# code.
System.Windows.Automation.AutomationElement ele = System.Windows.Automation.AutomationElement.FromHandle(handle);//handle is a window handle
UIA3Automation uiauto3 = new UIA3Automation();
FlaUI.Core.AutomationElements.AutomationElement flauiEle = uiauto3.WrapNativeElement(ele);//flaui has this conversion method, but the code throws an exception.

